# object of the game is to inherit CCNODE or NSObject in cocos2d-iphone

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i'm new cocos2d-iphone programmer, i developer a small game, I am confused about the object of the game is to inherit CCNODE or NSObject.
thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inherit CCNode if the object has to be added to the cocos2d node hierarchy via addChild. Inherit NSObject otherwise.

Comment: But logic object inherit CCNode is strange inherit style, so I confused.

Comment: There's a lot of strangeness if you work with cocos2d. That's why I'm adding MVC Cocoa-style to cocos2d with KoboldTouch. See: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/10/essential-cocos2d-koboldtouch/